# Can helm run different functions on multiple selections from different sources?

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I am trying to write a helm command to select email addresses from three sources: an aliases variable, org-contacts, and the contacts from mu4e. The command works fine, showing me candidates from all three sources. But, I need one function to act on the selections from the aliases, another to act on the org-contacts, and a third to act on the mu contacts, with the final result being a comma-separated list of email addresses that is inserted.

I can select multiple entries, but the function that gets called when I press enter is the default action for the source I am in, and it does not seem to get the the selected entries as an argument, and helm-marked-candidates doesn't seem to have all the selected entries in it. Here is a minimal example that allows multiple selections across sources, but where the multiple selections do not get passed to the respective functions. Any ideas on how to do that? Or if it is possible?

```
(setq helm-source1
  '((name                            . "source 1")
    (candidates                      . (1 2 3 4))
    (action . (lambda (x) (message-box "%s" (helm-marked-candidates))))))

(setq helm-source2
  '((name                            . "source 2")
    (candidates                      . ("a" "b" "c" "d"))
    (action . (lambda (x) (message-box "%s" (helm-marked-candidates))))))

(defun j-insert-emails ()
  "Helm interface to email addresses"
  (interactive)

  (helm :sources '(helm-source1
           helm-source2)))
```